# DIV same height

Tags: jquery, html, height

I have this jQuery script which make my two divs the same height:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var $sameHeightDivs = $('.sameh');
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $sameHeightDivs.each(function() {
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).outerHeight());
    });

    $sameHeightDivs.css({ height: maxHeight + 'px' });
});
```

I have two divs:

```
<div class="sameh">div 1</div>
<div class="sameh">div 2</div>
```

The problem is, that div 1 is loaded first (I think that is the problem), and actually DIV2 is higher than DIV1. But the script just makes these two divs same height, which will make DIV2 same height as DIV1.

How can I do, so DIV1 is following the height of DIV2?

Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, you can pass an integer argument to the `height()` method to set height, instead of using `.css(height: ...)`.

Comment: I can't actually see anything wrong with your code - it should work as far as I can see.

Comment: The code works fine there. Although if I add a lot of content to DIV2 and make it really long, it will only be as long as DIV1 and the rest of the content is simply just "hidden"

Comment: "How can I do, so DIV1 is following the height of DIV2" -- I'm afraid I don't understand what this means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the max height from all of the elements and then apply that to the others :

```
// get the max height of a collection of elements using map
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(".sameh").map(function ()
{
    return $(this).outerHeight();
}).get());
// set all divs to the same height
$('.sameh').css({ height: maxHeight + 'px' });
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/9yFzE/3/) and 
[Docs on .map() here](http://api.jquery.com/map/)